# Replacing same occurrences of a string by different values in ms-word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a text with five 'XX' scattered at different places. I'd like to
replace the first instance of XX by 1., the second instance by 2. and
so, until replacing the fifth instance by 5. I tried to use the
following code without success:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
  .Text = "XX"
  .Replacement.Text = "1."
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
  .Forward = True
  .Text = "XX"
  .Replacement.Text = "2."
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
  .Forward = True
  [...]
  .Text = "XX"
  .Replacement.Text = "5."
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
End With
End Sub
```

How can I modify the above code, or what else should I do to get these substitutions? If I use "sed" on a text file, I'd simply do: `s/XX/1./1`, `s/XX/2./2`, `s/XX/3./3`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use a `For...Next` loop to increment a counter, using the counter as the replacement text. This will save having to write lots of repeated code, as the first code sample shows.

The code can be made more flexible, for any number of occurrences of the search term, by using a `Do...Until` loop that repeats until no more instances of the search term are found. This variation is in the second code example.

Both variations contain code to search either the entire document or the current selection. Just comment out the one you don't need and remove the comment from the one you do...

```
Sub FindAndReplaceWithNumbers()
    Dim rngDoc As word.Range, rngFind As word.Range
    Dim findString As String
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim found As Boolean

    findString = "XX"
    'To search the entire document
    'Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.content
    'To search a selection, only
    Set rngDoc = Selection.Range
    Set rngFind = rngDoc.Duplicate
    With rngFind.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .wrap = wdFindStop
      .Forward = True
      .Text = findString
    End With
    For counter = 1 To 5
        With rngFind.Find
            .Replacement.Text = CStr(counter) & "."
            found = .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne)
        End With
        rngFind.End = rngDoc.End
    Next
End Sub

Sub FindAndReplaceWithNumbers()
    Dim rngDoc As word.Range, rngFind As word.Range
    Dim findString As String
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim found As Boolean

    findString = "XX"
    counter = 1
    'To search the entire document
    'Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.content
    'To search a selection, only
    Set rngDoc = Selection.Range
    Set rngFind = rngDoc.Duplicate
    With rngFind.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .wrap = wdFindStop
      .Forward = True
      .Text = findString
    End With
    Do
        With rngFind.Find
            .Replacement.Text = CStr(counter) & "."
            found = .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne)
        End With
        rngFind.End = rngDoc.End
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop Until Not found
End Sub
```

Comment: How would you do only for a selected text, not for the whole document.

Comment: I've adjusted my code so that it runs for the current selection. But I left in the entire document, commented out, in case you'd ever need that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simpler and faster:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "XX"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    i = i + 1
    .Text = i
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " records updated."
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works very well for the whole document. How could you do for a selected text? Is it enough to replace `ActiveDocument.Range` by `Selection`?

Answer (score 0):

To limit the code's scope to a Selection, you could use:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long
With Selection
  Set Rng = .Range
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "XX"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      If .InRange(Rng) Then
        i = i + 1
        .Text = i
      Else
        Exit Do
      End If
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " records updated."
End Sub
```